# form for multiple object - catches only last record

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this line in `controller/new` for multiple records form:

```
@students = Array.new(quantity) {@stream.students.build}
```

View file:

```
<%= @errors.inspect %>
<%= form_for :students_list, {:url => create_students_list_stream_url(@stream) } do |students_list_form| %>
<% i=0 %>

<% @students.each do |student| %>
<% i=i+1 %>
<%= students_list_form.fields_for student do |student_form|%>
<%= render :partial => "students/add_students_to_stream", locals: {:student=>student, :student_form=>student_form, :i=>i} %>
<% end %>
<% end %>
<%= students_list_form.submit "Добавить студентов" %>
<% end %>
```

This generates looking rather right HTML, for one input:

```
    <input id="name-field-1" type="text" name="students_list[student][account_attributes][name]" />
...
```

Note that it can be multiple objects per page, such as this input, as I want to create list of records.

But, as I can see from my server logs, params, which Rails gets, include only last record.

For example, I have forms for two 'students' on page.

```
 <input id="name-field-1" type="text" name="student[student][account_attributes][name]" />
 <input id="name-field-2" type="text" name="student[student][account_attributes][name]" />
```

And input there names John and Peter, my server logs will show:

```
"students_list"=>{"student"=>{"account_attributes"=>{"name"=>"Peter"}}}
```

and thats it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fields are named exactly the same and do not have array sign in name, that's why browser overwrites them.

To make browser post array - fields should end up named `students_list[][student][account_attributes][name]` (note the additional `[]`, by placing it in different parts of name you can control which elements are grouped)

So try `fields_for 'students_list[]', ...`

Answer (score 1):

In that case you must be adding `multiple="multiple"` and make name type as array.

html.

```
 <input id="name-field-1" type="text" multiple="multiple" name="student[student][account_attributes][name][]" />
```

rails.

```
<%= form.text_field :object, id: "id", multiple: true %>
```

So that would return all the elements as `Array` for a same field name.